# Koin testing on Androidx with Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-kotlin, koin

I am trying to do some instrumented tests of a boilerplate code after migrating it to AndroidX. Note that before migration, all of them worked, but after, only unit tests work, the instrumented test crashes on Null Pointer exception, where it shouldnt.

Here is the errror:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.reactivex.Flowable io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)' on a null object reference
02:55:31 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.buffer.android.boilerplate.data.interactor.FlowableUseCase.execute(FlowableUseCase.kt:26)
02:55:31 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.buffer.android.boilerplate.ui.browse.BrowseBufferoosViewModel.fetchBufferoos(BrowseBufferoosViewModel.kt:25)
02:55:31 V/InstrumentationResultParser: at org.buffer.android.boilerplate.ui.browse.BrowseActivity.onCreate(BrowseActivity.kt:40)
```

as you see, it's in the declaration of my "UseCase" in this case, get bufferoos. For reference, here is the class that fails:

[GetBufferoos](https://github.com/LukasAnda/bufferoo-androidx-migration/blob/master/data/src/main/java/org/buffer/android/boilerplate/data/browse/interactor/GetBufferoos.kt)

[Flowable Use case](https://github.com/LukasAnda/bufferoo-androidx-migration/blob/master/data/src/main/java/org/buffer/android/boilerplate/data/interactor/FlowableUseCase.kt)

Here is the test that fails

[ActivityTest](https://github.com/LukasAnda/bufferoo-androidx-migration/blob/master/mobile-ui/src/androidTest/java/org/buffer/android/boilerplate/ui/browse/BrowseActivityTest.kt)

Here is modules.kt for koin

[Modules](https://github.com/LukasAnda/bufferoo-androidx-migration/blob/master/mobile-ui/src/main/java/org/buffer/android/boilerplate/ui/di/modules.kt)

Comment: So `bufferooRepository.getBufferoos()` returns `null`? Please show some relevant Koin code.

Comment: Exactly, and I do not know why because in normal run everything works fine. Is it a problem with injecting ?

Comment: Most likely. That's why I'd like you to show form Koin related code near that repository and its factory.

Comment: @shkschneider i've edited my question with link to modules, that's where I wrap all things together

Comment: @shkschneider any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: I have a limited skill in Koin and fail to see the issue. I Simply upvoted your question as it seems legit

Comment: @shkschneider oh, thanks then :) Well, I think I might have to just go away with other instrumentation tests